# phonegap filereader onloadend doesn't work

Tags: html, cordova, cordova-2.0.0, cordova-3

I'm using phonegap to take a picture and put it into a img-container.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail);

var onSuccess =  function(imageURI) {
        var pic = document.getElementById('picture');
        pic.style.display = 'block';
        pic.src = imageURI;
};

var onFail = function(message) {
        $('#infoField').val(message);
};
```

That works perfect. Now I want to load the picture with a format to be alble to send it over a websocket. Therefor I use the fileReader and set the type to dataUrl.

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
      $('textarea#textarea1').val("evt triggered");
      //var socket = io.connect(addr);
      //socket.emit('mobilePicture', "works");
};

reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('picture').src);
```

Unfortunately nothing happens. The onloadend event isn't triggered anyhow. Any ideas?

Comment: just to be sure, you only start to read the file after you got the `onSuccess` callback from `getPicture`, right?

Comment: yes, I start the reader by pressing a button .. after taking the picture of course :)

Comment: Might be the path wrong? file:///storage/emulated/[...]/123.jpg
I changed it into file://storage ... but that didn't work either .. maybe sth else is wrong with it

Comment: you have to put the second part of your code inside the `onSuccess` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to re-arrange your code like this:

```
var onSuccess =  function(imageURI) {
        var pic = document.getElementById('picture');
        pic.style.display = 'block';
        pic.src = imageURI;

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
              $('textarea#textarea1').val("evt triggered");
              //var socket = io.connect(addr);
              //socket.emit('mobilePicture', "works");
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(imageURI);
};

var onFail = function(message) {
        $('#infoField').val(message);
};

navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail);
```

You have to pass a `file object` to the `file.reader` not just a path to the file.

**Edit / update:**
To find a file on your filesystem by a path first you will need to create a `fileEntry` using the `fileSystem`:

**Example**

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    //fileEntry
    alert("Got the fileEntry!");
    reader.readAsDataURL(fileEntry);
    ...
}
```

Comment: That looks great, unfortunately I receive a error code:5 from window.requestFileSystem ... I'm checking out where that can come from. (I'm using require.js+backbonejs for my app)

Comment: I use window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(document.getElementById('picture').src, gotFileEntry, fail); instead of root.getFile ... that works out .. thx for your help benka :)

Answer (score 0):

Using readAsDataURL may still result in corrupt images particularly with iOS. After hours of testing and research I can confirm another users findings on using **readAsBinaryString()** which changes handling the onloadend code too.

Reference post is at:
[Cordova - Reading Large Image corrupts image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392303/cordova-reading-large-image-corrupts-image)

To expand on @benka example and incorporate the command iOS is happy with the code might look like:

```
var onSuccess =  function(imageURI) {
var pic = document.getElementById('picture');
pic.style.display = 'block';
pic.src = imageURI;

var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
  $('textarea#textarea1').val("evt triggered");
  //var socket = io.connect(addr);
  //socket.emit('mobilePicture', "works");
  var base64 = window.btoa(evt.target.result); // Send this to a server.
  var image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64 ; // Use if you need a html src reference.
};

  reader.readAsBinaryString(imageURI);
};

var onFail = function(message) {
  $('#infoField').val(message);
};

navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13043506)

Comment: Thank you @michael-gaskill, I've added a new example merging the proposed edit.