# Cordova reader.onloadend is not fired

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, filereader

I'm making a cross platform app with cordova.

I want to get an image from photo library and preview it on screen and upload it to server.
I could do the image is displayed on screen so far.

The problem is reader.onloadend is not fired and nothing happens.

```
$scope.getImage = function() {

    var options = {
        quality: 100,
        sourceType: 0     // 0:Photo Library, 1=Camera, 2=Saved Album
    };

    var onSuccess =  function(imageURI) {
        var pic = document.getElementById('addImage');
        pic.style.display = 'block';
        pic.src = imageURI;

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            alert("loaded");
        };

        reader.onerror = function(error) {
            alert("error");
        };

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(imageURI);
    };

    var onFail = function(message) {
        alert("error");
    };
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, options);
};
```

I've been struggling this problem for 2 days and found exactly same thread [phonegap filereader onloadend doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073302/phonegap-filereader-onloadend-doesnt-work) but couldn't solve yet.

Does anyone have any suggestion?
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I identified this as an issue with zone.js in Angular 2.
A workaround is to wrap FileReader object into it's own zone.

```
const WrappedFileReader = window.FileReader
window.FileReader = function OriginalFileReader(...args) {
  WrappedFileReader.apply(this, args)
  const originalInstance = this[Zone.__symbol__('originalInstance')] // eslint-disable-line

  return originalInstance || this
}
```