# DataURI to Blob errors: DOM Exception 5: An invalid or illegal character was specified

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor, base64, blob

I'm using Meteor with a Cordova plugin to record a video on an iPhone, then convert that to a blob for uploading. About half of the time I try to convert the video from the local filesystem to a blob it works and the other half it gives this error:

```
InvalidCharacterError: DOM Exception 5: An invalid or illegal character was specified, such as in an XML name.
```

It seems like it usually happens when the video is longer than 3 seconds, but it has happened on the really short videos. Here is my `dataURItoBlob` function:

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
   var input = dataURI.replace(/\s/g, '');
   var binary = atob(input.split(',')[1]);
   var array = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
      array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
   }
   return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: "video/mp4"});
}
```

I'm really not sure what I am doing wrong and I have tried a couple other similar functions with no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried 4 other dataURI to Blob functions and they all give this error. Makes me think it's my dataURI that's the problem, but I can't see anything wrong with it. It has `data:video/mp4;base64,` at the beginning of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out this was a problem with the base64 dataURI, not the blob function. For some reason it was getting corrupted when trying to use `readAsDataUrl`. As per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392303/cordova-reading-large-image-corrupts-image), I solved it by `readAsBinaryData` and appending the `data:video/mp4;base64,` manually.

[Cordova - Reading Large Image corrupts image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392303/cordova-reading-large-image-corrupts-image)