# FileReader readAsDataURL result incomplete

Tags: android, cordova, base64, sapui5, filereader

My issue is very similar to this question [Cordova - Reading Large Image corrupts image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392303/cordova-reading-large-image-corrupts-image)
but I haven't had any success with the solution.  I'm also attempting to use the image picker plugin for Cordova

Cordova 7.0.1

Android 6.2.3

SapUI5 1.44.17

```
fileToBase64: function(fileUrl, callback) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileUrl, function(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function(file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(evt) {
                    callback(evt.target.result);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);

            }, function(error) {
                console.log("File entry error " + error);
            });
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("Resolve system file error " + error);
        });
    },
```

The result returned is an incomplete base64 string.  Here's the loop through my images

```
handleImagePicker: function(oEvent) {
        var _this = this;
        window.imagePicker.getPictures(
            function(results) {
                var numOfImagesLeftToProcess = results.length;
                if(numOfImagesLeftToProcess)
                    _this.appBusy(true);
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    _this.fileToBase64(results[i], function(base64Str) {
                        console.log(base64Str);
                        numOfImagesLeftToProcess--;
                        if(numOfImagesLeftToProcess == 0) {
                            _this.appBusy(false);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, function (error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + error);
            },
            {
                //outputType: imagePicker.OutputType.BASE64_STRING // default .FILE_URI
            }
        );
    },
```

Not sure if the callback is being called prematurely.  I'm able to view the images fine on the device and I've tested this code on two different devices with two different version of Android.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Upon further testing, same code runs fine on the iOS simulator.  On Android devices I only ever get 4000 characters in the console.log